# Not getting the glossy in the metallic material render

Tags: materials

So i know this question might be worded better but I'm literally new to blender.
Lemme sum it up:

I've learned blender through youtube tutorials to make Chrome effect typography.

I import the vector from illustrator, remesh it, sculp it then my problem starts with adding texture. I add an HDRI but still my material isn't looking as shiny or as glossy as I wanted to.
[image: my material viewport with metallic all way up to 1 and roughness in zero]

and here is my rendered view (too large to upload)
https://ibb.co/31M1cXY

what i want to achieve is this result of this video in 3:18
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWQwhoxFd7E&ab_channel=fxntxnile

i have no idea how to get this. i'm a newbie.

Comment: my rendered view also looks transparent af sometimes. idk where i went wrong. i've followed every tutorial step and even changed from eeve to cycles. still the same. with color base it kinds of approaches to the glossy thing but not really.

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file (at least a part of your object)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots i'm updating my blend file there but it's 6gb so it'll take some time (idk how to deliver it to you in a lighter format or something)

Comment: 6Go is huge, why is it so big?

Comment: no idea :( maybe the hdri?

Comment: wait no it's 618 mb LMAO but it's still taking ages

Comment: Hi Gina, haven't seen the tutorial yet but I guess this often comes down to which HDRI you are using and how much brightness they provide. Also the number of light sources in the HDRI or in your scene play a big role. And what I saw in the tutorial at a quick glance is that they've made a bulgy surface, which also reflects the environment much more dynamic and from different angles, where yours looks like a flat surface. What I can't tell from the screenshot is if it your object is set to _Shade Smooth_ or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may try add different lightsources like add a sunlamp to the HDR and increase the light power of the hdr. Try another HDR from https://polyhaven.com/  or another  resource side.